# masked input with javascript on a textbox

Tags: javascript, html

i am trying to mask input with jquery like this on my textbox but it is not doing anything:

```
 $(function() {
         $("#<%= received_dateTextbox.ClientID %>").mask("99/99/9999");
...
...
```

and i have also tried like this:

```
$('#received_dateTextbox').mask("99-9999999");
```

what am i doing wrong?

i have included this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery.maskedinput-1.2.2.js"></script>
```

here is the html:

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <table>
        <tr><td>Sample Received Date:</td>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="received_dateTextbox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>..........
```

here is the COMPLETE source:

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="LOMForm.aspx.cs" Inherits="EnterData.DataEntry.LOMForm" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css" media=screen>
    .TreeNodeOver 
{
 font-family: Tahoma;
 font-size: 8pt;
 color: black;
 text-decoration: underline; 
 cursor: pointer;
 cursor: hand;
 padding-left: 3px; 
}


<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" />

</style>



          <script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery.maskedinput-1.2.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery.multiselect.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">







    $(function() {
         $("#<%= received_dateTextbox.ClientID %>").mask("99/99/9999");
        $('table input:checkbox').click(function() {
            if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
                var checkText = $(this).next('a').text();
                if (checkText.indexOf('Liquid Handler #:') != -1) {
                    var userInput = prompt("Liquid Handler #:", "Liquid Handler #:");
                    $(this).next('a').html('Liquid Handler #:' + '<font color="red">' + userInput + '</font>');
                }
                if (checkText.indexOf('Olympus #:') != -1) {
                    var userInput = prompt("Olympus #:", "Olympus #:");
                    $(this).next('a').html('Olympus #:' + '<font color="red">' + userInput + '</font>');
                }
                if (checkText.indexOf('LC-MS/MS #:') != -1) {
                    var userInput = prompt("LC-MS/MS #:", "LC-MS/MS #:");
                    $(this).next('a').html('LC-MS/MS #:' + '<font color="red">' + userInput + '</font>');

                }
                if (checkText.indexOf('Liquid Handler#:') != -1) {
                    var userInput = prompt("Liquid Handler#:", "Liquid Handler#:");
                    $(this).next('a').html('Liquid Handler#:' + '<font color="red">' + userInput + '</font>');

                }
                if (checkText.indexOf('Olympus#:') != -1) {
                    var userInput = prompt("Olympus#:", "Olympus#:");
                    $(this).next('a').html('Olympus#:' + '<font color="red">' + userInput + '</font>');

                }
                if (checkText.indexOf('LC-MS/MS#:') != -1) {
                    var userInput = prompt("LC-MS/MS#:", "LC-MS/MS#:");
                    $(this).next('a').html('LC-MS/MS#:' + '<font color="red">' + userInput + '</font>');

                }
                if (checkText.indexOf('Wrong Practice Code') != -1) {

                    var userInput = prompt("Do you want to check Report Sent to Wrong Location/Physician?", "y/n");
                    if (userInput.indexOf('y') != -1) {
                        var elNode = document.getElementById("TreeView1n66CheckBox");
                        $(elNode).prop("checked", true);
                    }
                }
                if (checkText.indexOf('Other:') != -1) {
                    var userInput = prompt("Other:", "Other:");
                    $(this).next('a').html('Other:' + '<font color="red">' + userInput + '</font>');
                }

            }
        });
    });



</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <table>
        <tr><td>Sample Received Date:</td>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="received_dateTextbox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>


    <tr><td>Site Of Occurrence:</td><td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="site_of_occurrenceTextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td><td>Occurrence Date:</td><td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="occurrence_dateTextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td><td>Report Date:</td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="report_dateTextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>


    <tr><td>Specimen ID:</td><td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="spec_idTextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td><td>Batch ID:</td><td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="batch_idTextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td><td>Report Initiated By:</td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="report_byTextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    </table>
    <table>

    <tr><td>Problem Identified By:</td>
    <td>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkDESpec" runat="server" Text="DE/Spec Res"/></td>
            <td>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkLAB" runat="server" Text="LAB"/>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkCLS" runat="server" Text="CLS"/>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkPractice" runat="server" Text="Practice"/>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkBilling" runat="server" Text="Billing"/>
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSalesRep" runat="server" Text="Sales Rep"/>
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkOther" runat="server" Text="Other:"/>

                                        <asp:TextBox ID="otherTextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
       </table>



    </div>


    <asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server" ShowLines="True" 
        onselectednodechanged="TreeView1_SelectedNodeChanged" 
        ontreenodecheckchanged="TreeView1_TreeNodeCheckChanged" CssClass="mytreeview"
        >
        <Nodes>
            <asp:TreeNode Text="PreAnalytical" Value="PreAnalytical" Expanded="False">
                <asp:TreeNode Text="Labels" Value="Labels" Expanded="False">
                    <asp:TreeNode Text="Specimen collection device mislabeled/unlabeled by practice" 
                        Value="Specimen collection device mislabeled/unlabeled by practice" 
                        ShowCheckBox="True">
                    </asp:TreeNode>
                    <asp:TreeNode Text="Specimen mislabeled: in-house error (Lab or DE)" 
                        Value="Specimen mislabeled: in-house error (Lab or DE)" 
                        ShowCheckBox="True"></asp:TreeNode>
                </asp:TreeNode>
                <asp:TreeNode Text="Test Requisitions" Value="Test Requisitions" 
                    Expanded="False">
                    <asp:TreeNode Text="Missing: no form sent with specimen" 
                        Value="Missing: no form sent with specimen" ShowCheckBox="True"></asp:TreeNode>
                    <asp:TreeNode Text="Wrong (i.e. OT instead of ORAL, sister practice)" 
                        Value="Wrong (i.e. OT instead of ORAL, sister practice)" 
                        ShowCheckBox="True"></asp:TreeNode>
                    <asp:TreeNode Text="Other: Non-ML" Value="Other: Non-ML" ShowCheckBox="True"></asp:TreeNode>
                    <asp:TreeNode Text="Copies Received: New ID/Req. assigned" 
                        Value="Copies Received: New ID/Req. assigned" ShowCheckBox="True"></asp:TreeNode>
                    <asp:TreeNode Text="Incomplete/Blank Requisition Form" 
                        Value="Incomplete/Blank Requisition Form" ShowCheckBox="True"></asp:TreeNode>
                    <asp:TreeNode Text="2 Specimens: 1 Req" Value="2 Specimens: 1 Req" 
                        ShowCheckBox="True">
                    </asp:TreeNode>
                    <asp:TreeNode Text="2 Reqs: 1 Specimen" Value="2 Reqs: 1 Specimen" 
                        ShowCheckBox="True">
                    </asp:TreeNode>
                </asp:TreeNode>
                <asp:TreeNode Text="Validity" Value="Need POC Results Confirmed" 
                    Expanded="False">
                    <asp:TreeNode Text="Need POC Results Confirmed" Value="New Node"></asp:TreeNode>
                    <asp:TreeNode Text="POC Results Marked Incorrectly" Value="New Node">
                    </asp:TreeNode>
                    <asp:TreeNode Text="No Tests Ordered" Value="New Node"></asp:TreeNode>
                    <asp:TreeNode Text="SEC A Unclear" Value="New Node"></asp:TreeNode>
                </asp:TreeNode>
                <asp:TreeNode Text="Sales" Value="Sales" Expanded="False">
                    <asp:TreeNode Text="Practice is not entered in database" Value="New Node">
                    </asp:TreeNode>
                    <asp:TreeNode Text="CP has not been updated" Value="New Node"></asp:TreeNode>
                </asp:TreeNode>
                <asp:TreeNode Text="Other" Value="Other" Expanded="False">
                    <asp:TreeNode Text="Other" Value="New Node"></asp:TreeNode>
                </asp:TreeNode>
            </asp:TreeNode>
            <asp:TreeNode Text="Analytical" Value="Analytical" Expanded="False">
                <asp:TreeNode Text="Reagent Problem" Value="Reagent Problem" Expanded="False">
                    <asp:TreeNode ShowCheckBox="True" Text="QC Failure" Value="QC Failure">
                    </asp:TreeNode>
                    <asp:TreeNode ShowCheckBox="True" Text="QC Contamination" 
                        Value="QC Contamination"></asp:TreeNode>
                    <asp:TreeNode ShowCheckBox="True" Text="Absence of INSTD" 
                        Value="Absence of INSTD"></asp:TreeNode>
                </asp:TreeNode>
                <asp:TreeNode Text="Instrument Problem/Failure" 
                    Value="Instrument Problem/Failure" Expanded="False">
                    <asp:TreeNode ShowCheckBox="True" Text="Liquid Handler #:" 
                        Value="Liquid Handler #:"></asp:TreeNode>
                    <asp:TreeNode ShowCheckBox="True" Text="Olympus #:" Value="Olympus #:">
                    </asp:TreeNode>
                    <asp:TreeNode ShowCheckBox="True" Text="LC-MS/MS #:" Value="LC-MS/MS #:">
                    </asp:TreeNode>
                </asp:TreeNode>
                <asp:TreeNode Text="Processing Problem" Value="Processing Problem" 
                    Expanded="False">
                    <asp:TreeNode ShowCheckBox="True" Text="Aliquoting/Sample Processing" 
                        Value="Aliquoting/Sample Processing"></asp:TreeNode>
                    <asp:TreeNode ShowCheckBox="True" Text="Specimen Contamination/Carryover" 
                        Value="Specimen Contamination/Carryover"></asp:TreeNode>
                    <asp:TreeNode ShowCheckBox="True" Text="Plate Contamination" 
                        Value="Plate Contamination"></asp:TreeNode>
                    <asp:TreeNode ShowCheckBox="True" Text="Blank Contamination" 
                        Value="Blank Contamination"></asp:TreeNode>
                </asp:TreeNode>
                <asp:TreeNode Text="Delay in Production" Value="Delay in Production" 
                    Expanded="False">
                    <asp:TreeNode ShowCheckBox="True" Text="Liquid Handler#:" 
                        Value="Liquid Handler#:"></asp:TreeNode>
                    <asp:TreeNode ShowCheckBox="True" Text="Olympus#:" Value="Olympus#:">
                    </asp:TreeNode>
                    <asp:TreeNode ShowCheckBox="True" Text="LC-MS/MS#:" Value="LC-MS/MS#:">
                    </asp:TreeNode>
                </asp:TreeNode>
                <asp:TreeNode ShowCheckBox="True" Text="Operator Error" Value="Operator Error">
                </asp:TreeNode>
            </asp:TreeNode>
            <asp:TreeNode Text="Post-Analytical" Value="Post-Analytical" Expanded="False">
                <asp:TreeNode Text="Data Entry" Value="Data Entry" Expanded="False">
                    <asp:TreeNode ShowCheckBox="True" Text="Medications" Value="Medications">
                    </asp:TreeNode>
                    <asp:TreeNode ShowCheckBox="True" Text="Tests" Value="Tests"></asp:TreeNode>
                    <asp:TreeNode ShowCheckBox="True" Text="Collection Date" 
                        Value="Collection Date"></asp:TreeNode>
                    <asp:TreeNode ShowCheckBox="True" Text="Patient Name" Value="Patient Name">
                    </asp:TreeNode>
                    <asp:TreeNode ShowCheckBox="True" Text="DOB" Value="DOB"></asp:TreeNode>
                    <asp:TreeNode ShowCheckBox="True" Text="SSN" Value="SSN"></asp:TreeNode>
                    <asp:TreeNode ShowCheckBox="True" Text="Requesting Physician" 
                        Value="Requesting Physician"></asp:TreeNode>
                    <asp:TreeNode ShowCheckBox="True" Text="Wrong Practice Code" 
                        Value="Wrong Practice Code"></asp:TreeNode>
                    <asp:TreeNode ShowCheckBox="True" 
                        Text="Corrected Report - patient name &amp; all demos wrong" 
                        Value="Corrected Report - patient name &amp; all demos wrong">
                    </asp:TreeNode>
                    <asp:TreeNode ShowCheckBox="True" Text="Other" Value="Other"></asp:TreeNode>
                </asp:TreeNode>
                <asp:TreeNode Text="Practice Error" Value="Practice Error" Expanded="False">
                    <asp:TreeNode ShowCheckBox="True" Text="Medications" Value="Medications">
                    </asp:TreeNode>
                    <asp:TreeNode ShowCheckBox="True" Text="Tests" Value="Tests"></asp:TreeNode>
                    <asp:TreeNode ShowCheckBox="True" Text="Demographics" Value="Demographics">
                    </asp:TreeNode>
                    <asp:TreeNode ShowCheckBox="True" Text="Other" Value="Other"></asp:TreeNode>
                </asp:TreeNode>
                <asp:TreeNode Text="Sales Support/Client" Value="Sales Support/Client" 
                    Expanded="False">
                    <asp:TreeNode ShowCheckBox="True" Text="Wrong Report Template" 
                        Value="Wrong Report Template"></asp:TreeNode>
                    <asp:TreeNode ShowCheckBox="True" Text="Typo Practice Name or Phyisician" 
                        Value="Typo Practice Name or Phyisician"></asp:TreeNode>
                    <asp:TreeNode ShowCheckBox="True" Text="E-mail Address" Value="E-mail Address">
                    </asp:TreeNode>
                    <asp:TreeNode ShowCheckBox="True" Text="Fax Number" Value="Fax Number">
                    </asp:TreeNode>
                    <asp:TreeNode ShowCheckBox="True" Text="Custom Profile entered incorrectly" 
                        Value="Custom Profile entered incorrectly"></asp:TreeNode>
                    <asp:TreeNode ShowCheckBox="True" Text="Other" Value="Other"></asp:TreeNode>
                </asp:TreeNode>
                <asp:TreeNode Text="Sales" Value="Sales" Expanded="False">
                    <asp:TreeNode ShowCheckBox="True" Text="CP Update Needed" 
                        Value="CP Update Needed"></asp:TreeNode>
                    <asp:TreeNode ShowCheckBox="True" Text="Client Education Needed" 
                        Value="Client Education Needed"></asp:TreeNode>
                    <asp:TreeNode ShowCheckBox="True" Text="Other" Value="Other"></asp:TreeNode>
                </asp:TreeNode>
                <asp:TreeNode Text="Operator Error" Value="Operator Error" Expanded="False">
                    <asp:TreeNode ShowCheckBox="True" 
                        Text="Report Sent to Wrong Location/Physician" 
                        Value="Report Sent to Wrong Location/Physician"></asp:TreeNode>
                    <asp:TreeNode ShowCheckBox="True" Text="Other" Value="Other"></asp:TreeNode>
                </asp:TreeNode>
                <asp:TreeNode Text="Laboratory" Value="Laboratory" Expanded="False">
                    <asp:TreeNode ShowCheckBox="True" Text="Corrected Report - reporting error" 
                        Value="Corrected Report - reporting error"></asp:TreeNode>
                    <asp:TreeNode ShowCheckBox="True" Text="Physician Requested Repeat" 
                        Value="Physician Requested Repeat"></asp:TreeNode>
                    <asp:TreeNode ShowCheckBox="True" Text="Other" Value="Other"></asp:TreeNode>
                </asp:TreeNode>
            </asp:TreeNode>
            <asp:TreeNode Text="Other" Value="Other" Expanded="False">
                <asp:TreeNode ShowCheckBox="True" Text="QuikLab/MLIS Problem" 
                    Value="QuikLab/MLIS Problem"></asp:TreeNode>
                <asp:TreeNode ShowCheckBox="True" Text="Practice Complaint" 
                    Value="Practice Complaint"></asp:TreeNode>
                <asp:TreeNode ShowCheckBox="True" Text="Shipping (FedEx, UPS)" 
                    Value="Shipping (FedEx, UPS)"></asp:TreeNode>
                <asp:TreeNode ShowCheckBox="True" Text="Billing" Value="Billing"></asp:TreeNode>
                <asp:TreeNode ShowCheckBox="True" Text="Other:" Value="Other:"></asp:TreeNode>
            </asp:TreeNode>
        </Nodes>
    </asp:TreeView>



    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Submit" />



    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you include [the JS file](http://jquery-joshbush.googlecode.com/files/jquery.maskedinput-1.2.2.js) and reference it properly?

Comment: mask is not an out of the box jquery function. Which plugin are you using?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery.maskedinput-1.2.2.js"></script>

Comment: @devin ive updated please thank yuou!

Comment: Please post the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not enough information to answer this question. I would give the following suggestions:

1. Look for Javascript errors from the JS console and post it here(Firebug for Firefox or Chrome/Safari/IE dev tools).
2. Reduce your code to the bare minimum required to reproduce the problem and put it on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) and ask folks to look at it.

Answer (score 1):

firebug or developer tools from google chrome, will always give you a good hint of what is happening, sintax problem or even debugging possibilities